# Getting UITableViewCell Properties From Cell Row

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have been trying to learn the ways of UITableViewControllers and I have been encountering an error. Here is the relevant part of my code:

```
class celly : UITableViewCell {
var name : String = ""
} 

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    println(String((tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath.row) as! celly).name))
}
```

Here is the error for the second to last line (the `println(...)`). It is not the real error... I think :[)

```
Cannot find initializer for type 'String' that accepts an argument list of type '(String)'
```

Does anybody know why my line is not working?

Thanks a lot in advance. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Note: just running `(tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath.row) as! celly).name` gives an error of `'NSNumber' is not a subtype of 'NSIndexPath'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is incorrectly used `row`. Method `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` is accepting a `NSIndexPath`, so you have to call it with `indexPath` not with `indexPath.row`.

```
println(String((tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! celly).name))
```

To spot similar errors easily, you might consider destructuring statements into simple and readable ones:

Destructuring:

```
let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! celly
let name = cell.name

println(name)
```

*The error message is a bug and I would consider report it.*

Answer (score 0):

`tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath.row)` throws an error. The reason for this is that `cellForRowAtIndexPath()` takes an argument list of `NSIndexPath`, not an `Int`. By using `indexPath.row`, you're returning an `Int` rather than the required `NSIndexPath`. To fix this, simply remove the `.row`:

```
println((tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! celly).name)
```

and you should be able to run it.